# How to get AWS EC2 AMI image-id of a given operating system using Java sdk describe instances api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

How can I get AWS Ec2 image id using `describe instance` Java SDK api for a given operating system which is free tier as well for the given region?
I tried to use the `describe Instance api` but I don't know how to use `Filters`.

```
AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient().describeImages(new DescribeImagesRequest().withFilters(Arrays.asList(
        new Filter().withName("is-public").withValues("true"),
        new Filter().withName("some name i dont know").withValues("some values i dont know")
)))
```

I am struggling with getting an image Id, it returns a lot of images using only `is-public` filter. I want to get free tier eligible instances of core os only, no extra software installed like SQL server, etc.
I tried [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) but couldn't understand much.

To be very precise, I want to get the AMI ids of images which are given at AWS console while launching an Instance marked as *free tier eligible as shown in image below*

[image: ec2 amis in aws console]

Please give me a example code snippet for getting a `ubuntu 18.04 LTS` ami-id  of this free tier eligible Image shown in image above i.e. `ami-02d55cb47e83a99a0`. And suggest how can i change it to get AMI id for some another images like Suse or debian or redhat etc.

**P.S**:

I suppose these AMI ids are different for each region even for same operating system, I think the solution should include something like `region` for getting image id in that region. In the solution, please include the solution for `ap-south-1` as this screenshot is for this region.

**Edit 1**

I know it has something to do with Filtering `name` or `description`. I can use wildcards in the `withValue()`, like i want to search for AMI like `new Filter().withName("description").withValue("*ubuntu-18.04*")` where `*` is wildcard character. But it returns all the AMIs which contains `ubuntu-18.04` in description, including all those *paid AMIS* which have existing software installed. How can I filter to get only free tier eligible, basic, default ubuntu image.

Comment: If you do not know the value then I think you need query instead of filter ,  here is the aws-cli command convert it accordingly `aws ec2 describe-instances  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].ImageId"`

Comment: @Adiii Hi, the command you provided, seems like it gives the AMI ids of the instances in my account. I want to know the AMI ids before launching the instance, assuming there is no instance present. Let's say i want to get an free ami id of an ubuntu image? How can I get it using describe image api or any other way if possible.

Comment: @AWS PS Can you please throw some light on this?

Comment: I see, then you need `describe image` API. Here is the most official ubuntu distribution that you can filter. `aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=owner-id,Values=099720109477"` or get all images `aws ec2 describe-images`

Comment: Alright, now I see something that can be useful. Can you please tell me what this `099720109477` owner-id corresponds to? It is official AWS owner and provides free tier AMI ids?

Comment: The account that manage the ami, I think you'll get some thing about the account may be here but I'm not sure https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/describe-account.html

Answer (score 1):

Being free-tier eligible has more to do with the instance type, not so much with the AMI itself. By that logic, if you could find all AMIs that will work with a free-tier eligible instance type like `t2.micro`, it should serve your purpose. Fortunately, AWS Marketplace search has an `Instance Type` filter. The following Marketplace URL finds free AMIs by AWS in `ap-south-1` compatible with `t2.micro`:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search?page=1&filters=VendorId%2CPricingPlan%2CFulfillmentOptionType%2CRegion%2CAmi::InstanceType&VendorId=e6a5002c-6dd0-4d1e-8196-0a1d1857229b&PricingPlan=Free&FulfillmentOptionType=Ami&Region=ap-south-1&Ami::InstanceType=t2.micro

Do the same using AWS Java SDK to get the AMIs programmatically.